# Jsp Servlet - how to set and get session variables

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have four jsp pages, namely one.jsp, two.jsp, three.jsp and four.jsp and one servlet called projecs.java

servlet fetch data from db and shows on one.jsp where use select one of the rows and form action is se tto servlet again, which select data again and displays two.jsp. To summorize, servlet is executed before any jsp page is displayed.

Now I want to collect responses from all jsp pages and display at last on result.jsp page. I trying to use session variables but does not work since servlet is executed before every jsp page.

How can I solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in your servlet method doGet or doPost:

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
```

To save attribute in session:

```
session.setAttribute("uname","abc");
```

To get attribute from session:

```
String n=(String)session.getAttribute("uname");
```